# docker inspect killed container in az cli

Tags: azure, docker

I created a `resource group` and `4 container instances` in `Azure`. They executed JMeter command on start up. 3 containers ran for the expected amount of time (12h), one of the containers was killed after a few hours. I want to `docker inspect` the **killed container** to find out the reason it was killed (I suspect OOM).

This is what I have done:

1. I logged in to Azure using `az cli` locally under `PowerShell 7`
2. I ran `az container --help` and can see available commands are:[image]

I can't see a way to run `docker inspect` on a stopped container...
When I ran:
`az container exec --exec-command "docker inspect" --name c3 --resource-group my_resource_group`

I understandably get the `BadRequestError: Container Group c3 is stopped`

Can I `docker inspect` a stopped container in `az cli`?

Comment: probably you need `docker container inspect`?

Comment: According to this: https://aka.ms/cli_ref there is no such thing as `az docker` unless I am missing something from your comment?

Comment: actually I meant for the `--exec-command "docker inspect"` command but it won't matter since the container is stopped. is `az_container_show` not useful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_show

Comment: That is something. I ran `az container show --name c3 --resource-group my_resource_group` and the exit code was 255, which means the ssh threw an error. I presume that points to container being killed not because of OOM, however can I be sure? I don't know... Thank you for that @Krishna it still would nice to know if I can run `docker inspect` somehow...

Comment: Actually exit code of 137 would be OOM

Comment: may be now you can check for `container logs` to see if there were script failures

Comment: nothing informative in logs... mystery ;)